# Is Female Circumcision allowed in Islam?

Tags: sharia, sex, circumcision

I know this is a very clear question. But what do you think in the light of Islam?

Answer (score 1):

We were unable to find any Qur’anic verse that sheds light on this 
issue directly. However there are some books of Traditions and of 
Islamic jurisprudence and some other books, which take up a 
discussion on the issue of female circumcision. There is 
disagreement on this issue however, among all four schools of 
jurisprudence in Islam as well as with the Ja‘fariyyah sect of the 
Shi‘ites.
Some regard female circumcision to be as compulsory as male 
circumcision, such as the Shafi‘i and the Hanbali schools of 
jurisprudence.

- Some regard it as a Sunnah, i.e., something which would be a sin if disregarded intentionally. The Hanafi and the Maliki sects maintain this belief.
- Some books go so far as to regard this act as being desirable.
- Original Islamic jurisprudence literature endorses only male circumcision and regards female circumcision as not being Sunnah.

In my point of view, I think female circumcision should be forbidden as it is [unhealthy and hurts females](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Female_genital_mutilation#Complications).